# A chapter heading without the word "chapter" and number

Tags: memoir

I want one chapter without word “chapter” and its numbering in the heading, but I want an ToC entry using `memoir`. I use the following

```
\documentclass{memoir}% 
\makechapterstyle{mychapterstyle}{%
    \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]  {%
        \chaptitlefont\hrule height 0.5pt \vspace{1em}%
        {##1}\vspace{1em}\hrule height 0.5pt%
        }% 
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
        \chapnumfont\thechapter%
        }%
}
\newcommand{\chapsubhead}[1]{%
  \\{\normalsize #1}%
}
\chapterstyle{mychapterstyle}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\sffamily\bfseries}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\setparaheadstyle{\normalfont\sffamily}

\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\small\slshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\small\slshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\chapter[Test]% ToC entry
  { Test \chapsubhead{ }}

\end{document}
```

This results in this

[image]

I wand just the word “Test” without the lines and the chapter numbering

Thank you!

Comment: `\chapter*{Test}` + `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Test} `. Remember, when you are making a chapter style you should also design the unnumbered ones

Comment: @daleif, thank you. I have tried `\chapter*{Test} ` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Test}` that but it was not working.

Comment: Not working how?

Comment: @daleif, that’s a good question. It was the first thing that came in to my mind, since it is a built-in 'function' in TexStudio.

Comment: @daleif it does not work in the sense of it does not delete horizontal rules (which is very natural)

Comment: In a good design it shouldn't. Besides I'm on a tablet so hard to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}
    \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\chaptitlefont ##1}%
```

code

```
\documentclass{memoir}% 
\makechapterstyle{mychapterstyle}{%
    \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\chaptitlefont{##1}}%
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}% 
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}%
}
\newcommand{\chapsubhead}[1]{%
  \\{\normalsize #1}%
}
\chapterstyle{mychapterstyle}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\sffamily\bfseries}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\setparaheadstyle{\normalfont\sffamily}

\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\small\slshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\small\slshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\chapter[Test]% ToC entry
  { Test \chapsubhead{ }}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. But it still contains the lines.

Comment: @Adam answer edited.